# Dockerfile requiring GPG key when shared with someone else

Tags: python, docker, gnupg, dockerhub

I wrote a Dockerfile for a project I was working on, when I run with sudo docker image build it works fine, however without sudo it asks for my gpg secret key. Now this obviously means I can't share the Repo with anyone and have them build the image from the docker file. I don't understand why it requires this, or even where this is being sent in the repo for the person on the other end to not be able to run it either, especialy when the Docker is a simple :

```
FROM python:3.9.7-slim



RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt


WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app



RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH /app

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["/app/src/api/app.py"]
```

I've tried logging out of my local Docker, but it still requires a key, I've tried adding and removing parts of the Dockerfile, changing python image, but I can't seem to get the image to build without requiring a GPG key, even though I'm not wanting to push this to dockerhub or anything.
Any help would be very appreciated.

The person I send it to just gets "ERROR: failed to solve: python:3.9.7-slim: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials" (or whichever python image I try"

Comment: This is weird it should not ask for GPG key for pulling base images, GPG keys are used for logging into docker

Comment: Your Dockerfile's content isn't relevant to the problem, especially after you've already verified that the problem happens with any image you try so it isn't specific to the particular Dockerfile. Steps someone else could run on their own machine to see the problem themselves, by contrast, _would_ be relevant.

Comment: That said, if your key is used to authenticate to your Docker daemon, someone else would just use _their own_ key to authenticate to _their own_ daemon; there's no reason they'd need to have _your_ key, and thus no reason that this should stop you from sharing an exported image.

Comment: Sorry I may not have made it clear, it's not them getting the image, they're cloning the repo, and then running docker build image to build their own image with what's in my repo, but they get a "failed to solve: error getting credentials" error. They say they can build other images.

Comment: I can't tell from question whether (a) this happens when you build the image or (b) when you run the image, and I can't tell (a) if the error is coming from Docker or (b) if the error is coming from `app.py`. It **sounds** like it's coming from `app.py`, which means this really isn't a Docker question and we would need to see your Python code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: If the `requirements.txt` is trying to access something that requires credentials... well, we have no way of knowing that because you aren't sharing the file.

Comment: (part of why I suggested that, btw, is the error message "failed to solve" is in line with terminology used by logic trying to find a way to satisfy a dependency set -- of course, you can look at the context of the error message and figure out if that's the case, but you haven't shared that context with us so we can only guess at more precisely where things go south).

Comment: @larsks To me my question reads how I meant it, "sudo docker image build it works fine, however without sudo it asks for my gpg secret key." My problem is coming from trying to build the image.   However I seemed to have solved it by removing Docker Desktop, it seemed to be adding some credentials even when doing docker through CLI, which I was not aware of?  Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the file runs fine when not containerised, so I would assume that would have meant any requirements etc were not a problem? I think it may be solved now anyway, just need to try it on someone else's system when I get a chance. Thank you for your help

Comment: When not containerized, your requirements _are already installed_; when building the container, you're going through the act of installing them inside that container.

Comment: But then wouldn't they have run into errors when trying to pip install my requirements outside of the container?